# How to add firestore document with AutoID from Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In my functions I have the following:

```
await admin.firestore()
  .collection("development")
  .doc("development")
  .collection("users")
  .doc(userId)
  .collection("tokens")
  .doc("{autoId}")
  .set(token, {merge: true});
```

In the tokens collection, I want to create a document with an autoID. Everything else seems to be working fine. However, when I check my firestore, the document is named {autoId} instead of generating an actual ID.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just leave the argument to the last .doc blank - i.e. `.doc()`.  "{autoId}" is NOT a flag to Firestore - it's just a string.